# How can I delay sound in each single speaker with FMOD?

Tags: fmod

I setted up a sound with multichannelsupport so now I need to delay the sound in each single speaker. How can I do this with FMODex? Is it possible to do that?

Thanks for helping me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've got an answer to my question by myself and fmod.org. I have to use the `FMOD_DSP_TYPE_DELAY`. With this type I can set the delay for each channel up to 10 seconds. More informations could be found in the documentation from fmod.

~Update~

Some code for interested fmod users:

```
FMOD_System_CreateDSPByType(system, FMOD_DSP_TYPE_DELAY, &dspDelay);
FMOD_Channel_AddDSP(channel, dspDelay, 0);
FMOD_DSP_SetActive(dspDelay, true);

while(true) {
    FMOD_DSP_SetParameter(dspDelay, FMOD_DSP_DELAY_CH0, delayLeft);
    FMOD_DSP_SetParameter(dspDelay, FMOD_DSP_DELAY_CH1, delayRight);

    Sleep(10);
    FMOD_System_Update(system);
}
```